# Isometry group of a complete separable metric space is Polish?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete separable metric space, and endow $Iso(X,d)$ with the pointwise convergence topology.

I've seen a few sources say this is clearly a Polish group, but why is this this the case?

Comment: This is sort of an exercise, I think.  One approach is to fix a countable dense subset $E \subset X$ and show that the "restriction to $E$" map gives an embedding of $\mathrm{Iso}(X,d)$ into the Polish space $X^E$ (with its product topology) whose image is closed (hence complete).  A useful lemma is to show that a sequence of isometries $f_n$ converging pointwise on $E$ must actually converge pointwise on $X$, and the limit is again an isometry.

Comment: Indeed, by an Arzela-Ascoli type argument, the convergence is uniform on compact sets. This is helpful in showing that the operation of composition is jointly continuous.